# Como quebrar linha no Content do Pseudo elemento ::after ou ::before?

Tags: css, html5, css3, pseudo-elementos

Existe alguma forma de quebrar a linha de um texto que está no `content` de um pseudo elemento tipo o `::after` ou o `::before` ?

Considerando que algo como isso: `content: "<br> não quebra?";` ou isso `content: "não <br> quebra?";` não vai funcionar, quais opções teríamos para essa linha de conteúdo do `::after` "cair" para linha de baixo?

```css
.z::after {
  content: "::after não quebra?";
  color: red;
}
.z.x::after {
  content: "::after <br> não quebra?";
}
```

```html
<span class="z">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
<span class="z x">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível, segundo a [especificação `content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) a quebra de linha se dá com o caractere escapado `\A`, mas é preciso outra propriedade `white-space` desde que o valor seja `pre` (`pre`, `pre-line` ou `pre-wrap`).

```css
.z::after {
  content: "::after não quebra?";
  color: red;
}
.z.x::after {
  content: "::after \A quebrou?";
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="z">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
<span class="z x">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
```

Comment: Valeu Tio, vc está rápido no gatilho hein! :D

Answer (score 2):

Utilize "\A" para quebrar a linha em conjuto com o "white-space: pre;"

```css
.z::after {
  white-space: pre;
  content: "::after \A quebra?";
  color: red;
}
.z.x::after {
  white-space: pre;
  content: "::after \A quebra?";
}
```

```html
<span class="z">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
<span class="z x">como quebrar a linha aqui | </span><br>
```

[Fonte](https://blog.escapecreative.com/add-line-breaks-css-generated-content/)

Comment: Dessa vez foi quase, mas a outra resposta veio um pouco antes ;)